# Formal regular expression for a language over a,b,c such that a is never adjacent to b

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I am trying to write a regex query for a language with letters a,b,c such that a is never adjacent to b.

Can it be done by using only the alternation (plus), concatenation and repetition (multiplication) operators?

L = w belongs to {a,b,c}* such that a is never adjacent to b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Lets see if I recall enough formal language theory.)

Such a regular expression could be built with help of a DFA like this:

```
A = aA + cC + F      // only a or c can follow a
B = bB + cC + F      // only b or c can follow b
C = cC + aA + bB + F // any char can follow c
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are states representing the state when `a`, `b` and `c` respectively was the previous character. Since any character can follow `c` we can make `C` our start state. `F` being the final end state (end of string).

This DFA can be converted to a regular expression like this:

```
A = a*(cC+F) // eliminate recursion
B = b*(cC+F) // eliminate recursion

C = cC + aA + bB + F
  = cC + aa*(cC+F) + bb*(cC+F) + F       // substitute A and B
  = (c + aa*c + bb*c)C + aa*F + bb*F + F // regroup
  = (c + aa*c + bb*c)*(aa*F + bb*F + F)  // eliminate recursion
  = (c + aa*c + bb*c)*(aa* + bb* + e)F   // regroup
```

So the expression would be:

```
(c + aa*c + bb*c)*(aa* + bb* + e) // e being the empty/null string
```

Or in informal regex format:

```
(c|a+c|b+c)*(a+|b+)?
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
(a+c|b*c)*(a*|b*)
```

Comment: This reponse was a great crash course for me - I already knew how to read and write regexes, but I have never studied the thoery behind them. Thanks for the inspiration and a very clear explanation. (also, the informal regex can be shortened to "`((a*|b*)c)*(a*|b*)`" )